# SQL string search query

Tags: sql

Currently we have requirement like below.

```
Input @Filename ="233-sssee-FILENAMETYPE@ssss.xml"
```

In the DB I have column values like below.

```
FileType              Val

FILENAMETYPE      Direct
```

Now my requirement is to search for `FIleTYPE` in above table by passing  `@Filename` as parameter and that should return `Val` as response.

How to write a search query for this type?

Comment: FILENAMETYPE is file name column?

Comment: Which dbms? Table definitions, sample data , expected result - i.e. describe more and better, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement was not proper. Try below query:-

```
select output_column_name from table_name where FileType = '233-sssee-FILENAMETYPE@ssss.xml'
```

Comment: Input will come as '233-sssee-FILENAMETYPE@ssss.xml'.This value I need to check against FileType Column in the DB.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is your input & what is your output. So that I can help you.